Pull to Refresh not able to pull the data below and add that bounce effect in the UI
I am trying to implement pull down refresh in react native which I do have achieved but in the UI part it is still creating issue like in IOS if we pull down the content in the flatlist will go down a little bit then it will reload but in android it is not happening although a reload icon comes down which triggers refresh function but the content in flatlist do not goes down like IOS.
  const renderScene = SceneMap(
    tabs.reduce((scenes, tab) => {
      scenes[tab.id] = () => {

        if (shimmer) {
          return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.loadContainer}>
      <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={`rgb(${Colors.appPrimary})`} />
      <Text style={styles.text}>Loading...</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
          );
        }

        return tab.content.length > 0 ? (
          <FlatList
            data={tab.content}
            renderItem={({ item }) => renderEvent(item)}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.eventId}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.eventList}
            bounces={true}
            overScrollMode="never"
            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl
                  refreshing={refreshing}
                  onRefresh={handleResfresh}
                  colors={['#FF385C']}
              />
            }
            scrollEnabled={true}
            bouncesZoom={true} 
          />
        ) : (
          <ScrollView
              contentContainerStyle={styles.noEventsContainer}
              refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl
                  refreshing={refreshing}
                  onRefresh={handleResfresh}
                  colors={['#FF385C']}
                />
              }
            >
              <Text style={styles.noEventsText}>{Message.eventTab.noevent}</Text>
            </ScrollView>
        );}
      return scenes; 
    }, {} as Record<string, React.ComponentType<any>>)
  );

This is the code I am using it working correctly functionality wise but in the UI it is not working as expected in android but the same is working in IOS.
